# Visual Studio unable to download files from web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, ssl

I am writing a web service using the classic ASP.NET web services. I published the web service a set it up on IIS 7.5, everything works fine.

However I want my web service to use SSL.

So I created a self signed certificate, bound my site to https, disabled Anonymous authentication, enabled basic and windows authentication.

Now I have my web service using https and SSL and can access it by inputting my windows login name and password. However when adding the reference through visual studio, vs finds the web service and all the methods as expected but when I actually press the "add reference" button at the last page of the wizard which pops up, VS tells me that it was unable to download the files from the web service and asks if I want to skip them.

I'm lost and google isn't of much help. any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: You have the service code? Can't you directly add service to your project and create reference from there? Not the exact solution, but it should work.

Comment: I already did that, but now that my project almost finished it's time to go live

Comment: See if you can see some errors in Fiddler and if so post them here.

Comment: Does Visual Studio prompt you for credentials when you do add reference?

Comment: See http://forums.asp.net/t/1321063.aspx/1. You should be able to user your non secure reference and just update the address right?

Comment: Do you have the SSL cert installed on your dev machine?